# Sign of $\int_XTr(F_h^2)$

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, kahler-manifolds

Let $(E,h)\to X$ be a holmorphic Hermitian vector bundle over a compact Kahler manifold. Denote by $F_h$ the curvature of its Chern connection. Can we know a priori the sign of the quantity
$$\int_XTr(F_h^2)\wedge \omega^{n-2}$$
or if $X$ is a surface the sign of
$$\int_XTr(F_h^2)$$

Comment: Hi:) I think there is a chance that this question would get better answers  at mathoverflow. So, if you don't get answers here for a few days, you might try there. Also, you might want to say who is $\omega$ explicitly. (I guess that it is part of the data of the  Kahler manifold? the symplectic form?)